# Create a connection coming from a `spike_source_cell` in Arbor?

Tags: arbor-simulator

The [docs](https://docs.arbor-sim.org/en/latest/python/interconnectivity.html#arbor.connection) specify that in order to create a `connection` a `source` and `dest` are required (of type `cell_global_label` and `cell_local_label` respectively). For connections between cable cells this works fine because you can place labels on their `decor` and then use those labels in the `cell_global_label`, but how do I connect from a `spike_source_cell`?

Here's what I do for cable cells:

```py
arbor.connection(
  arbor.cell_global_label(gid, "soma_spike_detector"),
  arbor.cell_local_label("soma_synapse"),
  1,
  0.1
)
```

But since I can't create labels on a `spike_source_cell` it throws the following error:

```
RuntimeError: Model building error on cell 26: connection endpoint label "soma_spike_detector": label does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.arbor-sim.org/en/latest/concepts/spike_source_cell.html) on spike source cells mention:

> has one built-in source, which needs to be given a label to be used when forming connections from the cell;

So you can use the label that you gave when constructing `spike_source_cell`s as the label when constructing the `cell_global_label`:

```py
# When constructing the source cell
arbor.spike_source_cell(
  "spike_source",
  arbor.explicit_schedule([5, 10, 12])
)

# In the recipe's `connections_on`:
arbor.connection(
  arbor.cell_global_label(gid, "spike_source"),
  arbor.cell_local_label("soma_synapse"),
  1,
  0.1
)
```